# Gauge Integral: Non-Borel Spaces

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-integral, gauge-integral

Is there a gauge integral over non Borel spaces?
(My interest lies in finite measure spaces.)

It seems as the definition of the gauge integral crucially depends on the existence of open sets for a gauge, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ok let me check off my thread.*

The gauge integral crucially depends on precompactness.

Thus the Gauge integral rests on Borel spaces